# Size of API response is causing R12 timeout error on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

So I have an API running on heroku where one of the actions returns a large list (+300 items) of kites (via Kite.all in Rails).  What's happening is that I get an R12 Request timeout error.  Is there a way to avoid this?  I was thinking of a paginated response, but I wonder if there are better techniques out there?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things you can do.

1. Paginate - this would be the most recommended.
2. Increase the timeout. If its set to 60s, try setting it to 120s or more.
3. Identify the bottleneck or the most time consuming part of the request. It could be n+1 query problem, serialization library etc.
4. Only send required information in the response. Client of the API might not require all the information from kite. Send only minimal information and expose another API to get more detailed information about a particular kite.